# Lambda expressions mechanisms in Java

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-class

I just read in a book that when a lambda expression is assigned to a functional interface, then that sets the "target type" for the lambda and an instance of that type (that is, the functional interface's type) is created with the lambda expression used as implementation for the abstract method in the functional interface.

***My question***: If so, then does that mean lambdas aren't really standalone methods and as such a new type of element brought into the language, but are simply a more compact way for expressing an anonymous class and as such merely are added facility (just like generics) on the compiler's side?

Moreover, how do method references comply with that, in particular, static methods which are not associated with any objects? For example, when a method reference to an instance method is assigned to a functional interface then the encapsulating object for that method is used, but what happens in the case of a static method - those are not associated with any object.. ?

Comment: The JLS [section 15.27](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) on lambda expressions and [section 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) on method references has the answers for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, then does that mean lambdas aren't really standalone methods and as such a new type of element brought into the language,

Correct, lambdas are compiled into normal methods with a synthetic name

> but are simply a more compact way for expressing an anonymous class and as such merely are added facility (just like generics) on the compiler's side?

No, it's not only on the compiler side. There are is also code in the JVM involved, so that the compiler doesn't have to write class files for the lambdas.

> Moreover, how do method references comply with that, in particular, static methods which are not associated with any objects?

Method references are not different from lambdas: at runtime there has to be an object implementing the functional interface. Upon calling the "SAM" of the object this method will call the referenced method.

> For example, when a method reference to an instance method is assigned to a functional interface then the encapsulating object for that method is used,

No, it can't be used. Let's take the following example using a `System.out::println` method reference:

```
Arrays.asList("A", "B").forEach(System.out::println);
```

`List<E>.forEach()` expects a `Consumer<? super E>` which defines the method `void accept(E e)`. The compiler need to generate byte code and other information in the class file so that at runtime the JVM can generate a class implementing `Consumer<E>` with a method `void accept(E e)`. This generated method then calls `System.out.println(Object o)`.

The runtime generated class would look something like

```
class $$lambda$xy implements Consumer<Object> {
    private PrintStream out;

    $$lambda$xy(PrintStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    void accept(Object o) {
        out.println(o);
    }
}
```

---

Your question from the comment: "Why not directly assign to instance and its method?"

Let's expand the example a little bit:

```
static void helloWorld(Consumer<String> consumer) {
    consumer.apply("Hello World!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    helloWorld(System.out::println);
}
```

To compile this, the compiler has to generate bytecode that creates an object implementing `Consumer<String>` (so it can pass the object into `helloWorld()`). That object somehow has to store the information that upon calling it's `accept(x)` method it has to call `println(x)` on the `System.out` PrintStream.

Other languages may have other names or concepts for this kind of objects - in Java the established concept is "an anonymous class implementing the interface and an object of that anonymous class".

How does the object store this information? Well, you could invent some super cool new way to store this information. The Java Language designers decided that an anonymous class would be good enough - for the time being. But they had the foresight that if someone came along with a new idea to implement it in a more efficient way, this should be easy to integrate into the Java ecosystem (Java compiler and JVM).

So they also decided to create that anonymous class not at compile time but to let the compiler just write the necessary information into the class file. Now the JVM can at runtime decide on what the optimal way to store the information (calling the correct method on the correct object) is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. But I'm still having a hard time understanding that: why would "the JVM  generate a class implementing Consumer<E> with a method void accept(E e)" when that class with its implementation of the method are going to call the instance (via its actual object) to carry out the contract of the functional interface? Why not directly assign to instance and its method? Do you believe it's because the instance does not decoratively implement the interface?

Comment: @Learnerer I've updated my answer, hopefully this helps

Comment: maybe the confusion is due to interference between the programming model and the implementation mechanisms.. . I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, when a method reference to an instance method is assigned
>   to a functional interface then the encapsulating object for that
>   method is used, but what happens in the case of a static method -
>   those are not associated with any object..

That depends on context. Let say we have a static `Utils#trim(String)` method that will obviously trim given string.

And now, lest have a `List<String> list` and lets have some strings in it. We can do something like this:

`list.stream().map(Utils::trim).collect(Collectors.toList())`;

As you can see, in given context, we are using lambda static method reference in order to use every string in list as input argument of `Utils::trim` method.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm really not asking how to use lambdas or method references, I'm just trying to figure out the workings behind the scene - how they're actually implemented